# What is the meaning of select * in workbench Administration-client connection tab

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, workbench, connection

I have an AWS RDS Mysql instance, when I use mysql workbench to see the connected users it show the process they are running, but i dont understand the meaning of **Select *** in that list(image)

[image: Image here]

My database instance is consuming a lot of cpu and i dont know if those process are the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer to my question, if you left click on the row and the select the option **show in editor** it shows the complete query in the editor.